# Tickets 3.12A PHP line issue

Tags: php, backend, numeric

I have a TicketsCAD installation issue. I installed locally, and the install went fine, everything was well. Then, when I went to login to the admin backend, it gave me this error:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\incs\browser.inc.php on line 25

So, I went and checked the file, line 25:

```
$j=strpos($userAgent, $navigator)+$n+strlen($navigator)+1;
```

I don't immediately see anything wrong with this syntax. Any help would be much appreciated.

(FYI: I am not a super-programmer, as many of you are. Please go easy on me.)

PHP Version 7.2.4

**Here is the entire piece of code:**

```
$l = strlen($userAgent);
     for ($i=0; $i<count($browsers); $i++){
        $browser = $browsers[$i];
        $n = stristr($userAgent, $browser);
        if(strlen($n)>0){
     $version = "";
  $navigator = $browser;
$j = $pos+$n+strlen($navigator)+1;
```

Comment: The only thing than can be "non-numeric" in that statement is `$n`, but from the code you posted we don't know what may be in there

Comment: I added the full statement. Will you take a peek at that and let me know if you need further information? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ilie Pandia is right. `stristr` returns a string, not a number. Using it in the above statement for adding numbers together makes no sense. Perhaps `stripos` was meant. rather than `stristr` because n usually represents a number not a string like it is doing in its current case. Using it with `strlen` first though really leaves me scratching my head what the author of the code intended.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of seems like this particular file is REALLY buggy, and somewhat shoddily written. Thanks for the attempted assist anyway. I guess I am going to have to send them a help request ticket.